# How to install a NuGet package on the command line to a Visual Studio project

Tags: nuget

I downloaded nuget.exe and I have tried the install. I would like to target a Visual Studio project so it adds a reference on the command line outside of Visual Studio. It is simply downloading the package with a version number on the end. MyOutputDirectory is the output directory which has a Visual studio solution there.

```
nuget install nhibernate -o MyOutputDirectory
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The NuGet Command Line does not actually **install** any packages. The install command is actually doing a **restore** operation.

This means that nuget.exe install will only download and extract the package into the output location. It will **not** modify the project file (so no references are added, no content files injected, no transformations applied, no MSBuild files imported), and it will also **not** run any PowerShell scripts.

I do believe that a similar request to yours is being tracked by the NuGet team, but feel free to log an issue there: http://nuget.codeplex.com.

To answer your question: the NuGet Command Line does not support your scenario at this moment (nuget.exe v2.8).

Comment: Okay, no problem.  I am building a code generator that will support NuGet.  It looks like I will be doing all this logic myself after the nuget.exe downloads the files.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Has this changed at all in later versions (v2.8) ?

Comment: @JohnSimons nope, not yet. Updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 22):

Well, it's not command line per se, but you can do this through the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio (accessed via `Tools > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console`). When installing a package to multiple projects, the Package Manager Console is still better than the "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution" dialog because you can paste a list of project names instead of selecting them one by one in the dialog.

Use a command such as this:

```
Get-Project MyProject1,MyProject2,MyProject3 | Install-Package MyPackage
```

Source: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5526926/289770).

If you are tempted to try to use this command from outside Visual Studio, read these questions:

- [Use NuGet powershell commandlets from outside Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884282/use-nuget-powershell-commandlets-from-outside-visual-studio)
- [Using NuGet Package Manager console outside Visual Studio to run Entity Framework Migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903711/using-nuget-package-manager-console-outside-visual-studio)