# How to force Nuget Restore using Powershell?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, package, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I'd like to force NuGet to restore my NuGet packages. Going to my solutions directory and type `NuGet restore`, even with the latest downloaded `NuGet.exe` doesn't work.

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903711/using-nuget-package-manager-console-outside-visual-studio-to-run-entity-framewor), I can do this in a Powershell prompt, using the `Update-Package` command (as I prefer not to use my Visual Studio environment).

However, my Powershell seems not to understand `Update-Package`, although I have a +5 version:

```
PowerShell Prompt> Get-Host | Select-Object Version

Version
-------
5.1.19041.1023


PowerShell Prompt> Update-Package -reinstall
Update-Package : The term 'Update-Package' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that 
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Update-Package -reinstall
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Update-Package:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What can I do in order to launch `Update-Package` successfully in my Powershell?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard powershell doesn't ship have NuGet restore functionality.

If you refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio, and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore, you will see that there are 5 ways to use NuGet.

- Visual Studio (and MSBuild.exe)
- Visual Studio for Mac
- dotnet CLI
- NuGet.exe CLI
- Package Manager Console (in Visual Studio)

There is no functionality built into powershell.

Your only options are to build on top of the above mentioned tooling.

- Call dotnet.exe restore
- Call nuget.exe restore
- Call msbuild.exe restore.

Answer (score 4):

You can try `Update-Package -reinstall` command in `Package Manager Console`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Update-Package, but the following:

```
 & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\
       Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
   /t:restore C:\code\projectdirectory
```

You may have to change the path to `MSBuild.exe`.

Not native PowerShell, but it works.